# How AltBean/Android manages active and passive BLE scan? Is it possible to set the library to perform only passive scans?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

If I understood AltBeacon's [Power Manager](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/battery_manager.html) documentation correctly. On Android 5+ devices, the library will continuously (or every few seconds) perform passive scans and, from time to time, it will also perform active scans. The active scan timings are controlled by `setBackgroundScanPeriod` and `setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod` BeaconManager's methods.

In my case, the beacons we are working with advertise at a constant rate and it don't send additional information on active scan (SCAN_REQ).

Thinking about power consumption, I wonder if there is a way to use the library to disable active scans, i. e. perform only passive scans AND get all (or as much as possible) advertising packets sent by my beacons, once my Android device is near that beacon. In summary, we want to detect the beacon's presence as soon as possible and, once detected, register all advertising packets, using only passive scan.

Is that possible? If so, how do I use the library to get this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points:

1. When the library documentation refers to active vs passive scan, it is not talking about sending a SCAN_REQ.  A "passive" scan just means a low power Android scan with a hardware packet filter that offloads the scanning to the Bluetooth chip.  The chip then wakes up the OS if it sees a packet that matches a pattern.  On the sense of your question, though, ALL the scans done by the library are passive.
2. Terminology differences aside, if you want to only do the filtered low power scans described above, you can just set the background scan period to 0.  This will likely work on Android 8+ devices.  On Android 5-7, it may not work as the full on filtered scan is used to parse actual packets.